# Extracting a bzip2 file throws "Can't guess original name" and does not extract separate files

Tags: linux, bzip2

I made a `bzip2` file by

```
bzip2 -c /home/os/picture1 > /home/os/Desktop/pic.image

bzip2 -c /home/os/picture2 >> /home/os/Desktop/pic.image
```

But now extracting `pic.image` by `bzip2 -d /home/os/Desktop/pic.image` returns

```
bzip2: Can't guess original name for pic.image -- using pic.image.out
```

and then it just creates one file `pic.image.out`.

How do I access `picture1` and `picture2` from `pic.image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

bzip2 is compression only. If you want file packing then you need to use tar as well.

Comment: And from the documentation: *If the file does not end in one of the recognised endings, .bz2, .bz, .tbz2 or .tbz, bzip2 complains that it cannot guess the name of the original file, and uses the original name with .out appended.*

Comment: so...now...there is no hack to access picture1 or picture2 from pic.image?? :-o

Answer (score 1):

You should use tar instead :

```
tar cjf /path/to/pics.tar.bz2 /path/pic1 /path/pic2
tar xjf /path/to/pics.tar.bz2 -C /path/to/extract/
```

Comment: Okay got you. BUT my file's extension is not .tar.bz2. It's just .image. What do you suggest to get my picture1 and picture2 from pic.image? Got any hack in mind??

Comment: hmm, all i can think of is writing a script that reads the file and extracts based on the bzip2 header, however there's no way of restoring the original file names that way.